# Using tangent substitution on $\Bbb R$

Tags: calculus, integration

How can you calculate de integral of $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ , $f(x)=\dfrac1{3\cos x+\sin x+1}$? I have done it with tangent substitution but that works if $x$ is in $(-\pi,\pi)$ and I don't know how to extend that to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Note that $f$ is periodic with any period of length $2\pi$. Thus knowing an antiderivative on $[-\pi,\pi]$ is enough...

Comment: On -pi and pi would you need to put c1 and c2 and calculate them from the continuity?

Comment: The issue is that if your function possesses asymptotes, for example near $x=2.1$. Any antiderivative makes sense only in intervals of continuity... Keep your answer as it is, adding it an arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the discontinuous curve associated with your function :

[image]

It possesses separated domains $D_k$, due to asymptotes : on each one, if $F(x)$ is your antiderivative, you can give the answer $F(x)+C_k$, on each $D_k$ with a specific $C_k$, independent of the others.